# Electron task getting stuck due to exe output

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to electron.js . I need to trigger a exe file on click of a button and read output of the command prompt of that process and get it's output in a textarea in my html.Kindly help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try [child_process.execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback). Example from the docs:

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const child = execFile('node', ['--version'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```